# Bash Shortcuts not Working

Tags: bash

I often ssh to a server that has a Bash shell. Previously all the normal shortcuts worked i.e. `up` would be last command, `ctrl+r` would allow me to search the previous commands.

However I logged on today and these no longer work e.g. `up` now displays `^[A` and `ctrl+r` displays `^R`. How can I revert it back to how it was before?

Comment: Are you sure the remote shell is `bash` and not `sh`? What is the output of `ps aux | grep $$`?

Comment: I get a -ksh and grep process

Comment: I think this must have changed as before it was definitely -bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post my comment as an answer. It sounds like the remote shell you are using is not bash. You can check by running `ps -p $$`. If that does not output `bash` you are running another shell.

To set your default shell to bash again, you can run this command:

```
chsh USER
```

Where `USER` is your username on the remote server.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps your `emacs-mode` is not set to `on`.

You can check with `set -o` if `emacs` is `on`.

If it's not `on` you can set it with `set -o emacs`.

Also check if `vi` is `off`. (and else set it to `off` with `set +o vi`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, this has worked for `up`, but `ctrl + r` still isn't working?!

Comment: Mmm, haven't had that before. Could you do a `bind -p | grep -i search` to check if you have a keyboard binding for `"\C-r": reverse-search-history`?

Comment: If its not there you could do a restart (i deleted my keybinding and it returned afterwards). Or else you could do `bind '"\C-r": reverse-search-history'` but i don't know if it's another issue if this survives a restart.

Comment: Hi Rik, the shell had been changed to `ksh`. I now just have to type  `bash` and everything is working again. Thanks for the help.